# Can not map Enum value with @mapper

Tags: java, spring, interface, mapper

I'm trying to make an automatic mapper, but I'm having a problem with an `Enum` inside my DTO.
In my `@mapper` class, I want everything to be automatically mapped except fthe `Enum` field. However, when debugging, I see that it does go into the mapper auto-implementation class, and it doesn't ignore my `Enum` as I indicate with @mapping

Example of my Entity and DTO

```
@Entity
public class Document {
    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private String type;
```

My DTO:

```
@Data
public class DocumentDTO {

private Integer id;
private DocumentsEnum type;
```

How can I ignore the mapping for that specific enumerated field?

I have tried the following annotations on @mapping:

```
@Mapper
public interface DocumentsMapper {

@Mapping(source = "type", target = "type", ignore = true)
@Mapping(source = "DocumentsEnum", target = "DocumentsEnum", ignore = true)
@Mapping(source = "MAIN", target = "MAIN", ignore = true) // <-- This is the value of Enum
@Mapping(source = "ppal", target = "ppal", ignore = true) // <-- This is the name of Enum
List<DocumentDTO> mapper(List<Document> document);

@AfterMapping
default void afterMapping(Document document, @MappingTarget DocumentDTO documentDTO) {
    //some logic
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to declare your `Mapping` to ignore the field you want to ignore is the first one, you can delete the others.

> ```
> @Mapping(source = "type", target = "type", ignore = true)
> ```

The reason that this isn't working for you as written is that you are technically mapping a `List` object to another `List` object.  The `List` objects you pass in to be mapped will probably not have a `type` field (and definitely not the one you care about), the objects they hold (`Document` and `DocumentDTO`) will though.

To get this to work they way you would like you need two mappers: one for the `List`s and one for `Document` to `DocumentDTO`.  Since the `type` field you want to ignore is on the latter objects, you should put the `Mapping` annotation on that method:

```
@Mapper
public interface DocumentsMapper {

List<DocumentDTO> listMapper(List<Document> document);

@Mapping(source = "type", target = "type", ignore = true)
DocumentDTO mapper(Document document);
```

The `mapstruct` library is smart enough to automatically use the `mapper` method to convert each element in your `List` in the `listMapper` method.